# Send list or array of data to JAXRS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I have data as below:

```
 $scope.companies = [
                { 'name':'Infosys Technologies',
                    'employees': 125000,
                    'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                    { 'name':'Cognizant Technologies',
                        'employees': 100000,
                        'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                        { 'name':'Wipro',
                            'employees': 115000,
                            'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                            { 'name':'Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)',
                                'employees': 150000,
                                'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                                { 'name':'HCL Technologies',
                                    'employees': 90000,
                                    'headoffice': 'Noida'},

                ];
```

I have UI to add more data for the above list. 
I want to send this data to persists. I am using JAX-RS. Best way to pass such data to services. I tried passing my_obj from below code.

```
    var my_obj = JSON.stringify($scope.companies);
```

But it is having hashcode, so not compatable to my POJO (Country.java)

**EDIT**

[image]

```
@POST
@Path("post")
@Consumes(value=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String post(@PathParam("countries") List<Countries> countries){

    return "Sucess!";
}
```

Here `countries` are empty. What went wrong?

JS code:

```
    var paramz =  "countries="+ my_jsonObj;
    http.open("POST", urrl, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.send(paramz);
```

Comment: You can have **@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)** in your service class and then while sending data to service set **datatype** to JSON. Also make sure the method which is going to handle this request should have **List<Country> countries** as argument.

Comment: If you're using Jackson in the back to deserialize JSON to a Java object, which some JAX-RS based frameworks do, you can annotate the class to which the JSON should be converted with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` and that will simply ignore any unknown properties found in the received JSON and only map those values that have a matching representation also in the class definition.